# How to create a dataframe from a nested dicitonary having variable keys?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my use case, I have a dictionary as given below:

```
d = {'Tom' :{'A' : '25', 'B' : '34'}, 'Jim' : {'A' : '34', 'B' : '19'}, 'john' : {'A' :'56' , 'B' : '32'}}
```

How can I create a dataframe from it as given below?

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 25 | 34 |
| Jim | 34 | 19 |
| John | 56 | 32 |

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
print (df)
       A   B
Tom   25  34
Jim   34  19
john  56  32
```

Or `DataFrame` with transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).T
print (df)
       A   B
Tom   25  34
Jim   34  19
john  56  32
```